# Differences between OpenSSH and AutoSSH

Tags: ssh

Is OpenSSH an implementation of a SSH server? Is it also an implementation of a SSH client?

Is AutoSSH not an implementation of  SSH server? Is it an implementation of a SSH client?

Answer (score 4):

> Is OpenSSH an implementation of a SSH server?
>   Is it also an implementation of a SSH client?

OpenSSH provides both, a server and a client implementation.

> Is AutoSSH not an implementation of SSH server? Is it an implementation of a SSH client?

Neither, *autossh* is just a wrapper around *ssh*.

> autossh is a program to start a copy of ssh and monitor it, restarting it as necessary should it die or stop passing traffic.

[Source](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/)

Answer (score 3):

> Is OpenSSH an implementation of a SSH server? Is it also an implementation of a SSH client?

Yes. You can find out on [official website](http://www.openssh.com/)

---

> Is AutoSSH not an implementation of SSH server? Is it an implementation of a SSH client?

No. You can read from manual pages ([`man autossh`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh)):

> autossh is a program to start a copy of ssh and monitor it, restarting it as necessary should it die or stop passing traffic.

Comment: Yes. It is neither of it. It is just wrapper around client (ssh) as manual says.